# Word for "the books a person is reading"

Tags: single-word-requests

> My usual ____ include science fiction and philosophy.

What is a word that means "books I'm reading"? Equivalent to "parlance" as far as parlance refers to the words or types of words a person likes to use.

Comment: Genres, or for a list of such books, reading list.

Comment: Are you looking for the specific books one is reading at the time of the question or the books one generally reads, regardless of what they might be reading at that time?  That is, I generally read SF but currently I'm reading books on project management and workplace innovation (work).  I think Clare is correct on both accounts -- ***Genres***  and ***Reading List***, respectively.

Comment: Have you got something against "My usual **reading** includes science fiction, philosophy, and romance."?

Comment: Informally, you could use 'my usual *reads*', similar to *eats* for meals on the go.

Comment: My bookshelf includes etc.?  I've seen this done digitally.  Or: My favorite reads?

Comment: I'd say "my usual **reading choices** include....."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Reading*** -- [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/reading#reading__8)

> *noun* 3. (uncountable) something that you read
>   *This report is my bedtime reading at the moment.*

And as others have mentioned, ***genres, reading list, reading choices, reads***, etc. are all equally valid.